# Generic purpose fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I do not want to create new `Activity` for each task as the business logic is handled by custom `Fragment` already. There is a generic layout:

```
<FrameLayout .. >
  <LinearLayout ..
    android:id="@+id/fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I wanted to create generic `Activity` that would use it and be initialized by a specific `Fragment`.

```
public class LeliFragmentActivity extends LeliBaseActivity {
public static final String KEY_FRAGMENT = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".FRAGMENT";

protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_fragment);

    Fragment fragment = (Fragment ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(KEY_FRAGMENT);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, calcFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

public static void start(Context c, LeliBaseFragment fragment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(c, LeliFragmentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_FRAGMENT, fragment);
    c.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I feel that this not a good way. Passing `Fragment` in the `Intent` seems to me as overkill. All this serialization is costly. I could pass class name instead .. Or is there better way? Or shall I have one `Activity` for each (full screen) `Fragment`? Thanks for hint.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the `Fragment` to a new `Activity`? Wouldn't it be displaying new/different information anyway? Why not just instantiate a new `Fragment` in the new `Activity`, then pass whatever data the new `Fragment` needs in the `Intent`?

Comment: Yeah I find this difficult to answer because it doesn't make sense. What use case are you trying to solve for? Because it might not have anything to do with the current solution path you are down

Comment: I do not want to have many copy pasted activities that differ just by name of the Fragment.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, you *might* be able to create multiple instances of the same `Activity` and pass in the type of `Fragment` it should create, but this sounds like a lot more trouble than it's worth. This still doesn't explain why you want to pass the *entire* `Fragment`, and not just the data that the new `Activity` needs, even if that data is just the type of `Fragment` that should be instantiated.

Comment: So the answer is that I was wrong with this approach. Thanks

Comment: I think so, if I understand what you want to do. I should be able to suggest an alternate approach, but some more context on your specific use-case would be helpful.

Comment: I will implement a parent activity holding the repeated code and a trivial Activity extending the parent that will provide the Fragment. I do not like copy pasted code as it is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Why not just make multiple activities then? Instead of multiple fragments. Will the fragments be used anywhere other than a single `Activity`?

Comment: This one particular Fragment was originally used in Tabs so it had to be Fragment. And anyway I have a feeling that Google is pushing Fragments as a preferred pattern.

Comment: @LeosLiterak This is a great question actually. How did you solve it in the end?

Comment: I create new activity class for each fragment.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

You can use one `Activity` for whole project if it's convenient for you and project is not too big. But if project is big and contains a lot of `Fragment`s it's better to divide them into logical order on different activities. For example `LoginActivity` will represent all sing/registration flow with many `Fragment`s. Than `LeliFragmentActivity` with all needed `Fragment`s

**Second**

You don't have to pass your `Fragment`s to each other. To communication between Fragment the best and simple way to use [intrefaces](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) like documentation says.

Other possible way to communication is event bus libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto).

Comment: Thanks for a response but my intention was different. I did not want to have one bloated Activity with tens of if-else. I wanted to have single simple Activity that once render ChartsFragment and then BadgesFragment or LoginFragment.

Comment: @LeosLiterak What is the problem with it?

Comment: see my discussion with @bryan

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
https://gist.github.com/burnermanx/8e80e160dfba2f758546c037fce5269a

I made it based on your question, but it will not be useful for me for now.